# jquery datatables not work after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

when I use template contains datatables and I use ajax

Before processing ajax the top of datatables there are any features such

- record per page
- search
- and automate pagging in bottom of table

but after Ajax load the features such list in above is missing
I just use simple ajax load

```
success: function({
    $("#tbl").load("contents/tbl-chat.php");
)}
```

and after load them the features of datatables is missing, so why to use datatables features after ajax load..

Thank. . .

Comment: can u provide a fiddle without ajax mate..??

Comment: I tried without ajax, but always not work. I still confuse where I must set .on if datatable included

Comment: please provide a demo by creating a fiddle in jsfiddle.net